# There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Primary key not found.'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When trying to add a scaffolded controller using "API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework", I get the error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:  'Primary key not found.'

By purpose my model do not have any ID, and therefore I have added a call to the `HasNoKey()` function, but still I get the above error.

This is my model:

```
 public class Tag
 {
     public DateTime DateTimeRef { get; set; }
     public double Data { get; set; }
 }
```

And this is my context class:

```
public class TagContext : DbContext
{
    public TagContext(DbContextOptions<TagContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>(e => { e.HasNoKey(); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it will help: modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>(e => { e.HasNoKey(); e.ToView("View_Tag"); }); But if your DbSet <Tag> will be used as a database entity, it must contain Id. Entity Framework needs to know the key to keep track on the object when you make an update or delete operation.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. While it did not really help me, it got me thinking, and I have ended up solving this by writing the controller manually. After all its a call to a stored procedure, and in that case, I don't need nor can have create, update and delete operations anyway.